# "Install UBUNTU along side windows 7" option is not showing

Tags: 12.04

motherboard = ASUS F2 A85-M
processor = amd A10 5800k
hard drive seagate 2 tb

I have installed windows 7 , now I want to install UBUNTU 12.04 along side with windows, but, when I am inserting UBUNTU 12.04 .iso cd, "Install UBUNTU along side windows 7"  option is not showing. Instead it is showing only two options - "erase disk and install ubuntu " and "something else" only these two options.

how to get rid of this problem.please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The "**Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**" option appears when you have free, unallocated (unpartitioned) space on your hard disk. Use your favorite partitioning tool to shrink the size of one of your partitions. Or, in your Windows 7, right click My Computer > Manage > Disk Management, and "shrink" (reduce the size of) one of your partitions to leave empty space for Ubuntu to be installed in. Once you do that, go back to installing Ubuntu, and you should see the "alongside" option available.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too. Probably you don't a spare partition to install Ubuntu. Use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or some similar software to edit partition and make one empty for Ubuntu to be installed. Remember to backup your data before you edit partitions.

After you do this you will see the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

I hope this helps.